# Is C# installed on Ubuntu by default

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#

So I'm trying to learn some new languages, and I figured C# would be good. I went to search how to install it on Ubuntu, and go 0 results, so I went to VSCode and tried to write an application, but then got this: `/bin/sh: 1: scriptcs: not found`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is C# installed on Ubuntu (by default)?**

No. C# is a programming language that is used primarily for Windows-based solutions. If you would like to develop with C# and the .Net Framework, you may be interested in [the Mono Project](https://www.mono-project.com/), which is for cross-platform development, primarily with C# and the CLR.

Comment: when doing `sudo apt install mono-devel` I get the error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdiplus : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: .NET Core has been available for Linux and mac for years. No one uses mono for modern projects

Comment: could you be more specific on how to do that, or could I use wine to install visual studio